# Data Frame Subset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Below I have code listed. I have data frame a which has many columns I am attempting to query a subset of two columns 'Rank' & 'Country' from data frame a into my new data frame. Why does this code not work?

```
df= a['Rank', 'Country']
```

If I use

```
df=a['Rank']
```

It works fine.

Comment: Have a look at their documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics
This should answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need another `[]`:

```
df= a[['Rank', 'Country']]
```

what is same as, but it is less typing:

```
df = a.loc[:, ['Rank', 'Country']]
```

Sample:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'Rank':[1,2,3],
                   'Country':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (a)
   C  Country  Rank
0  7        4     1
1  8        5     2
2  9        6     3

df = a.loc[:, ['Rank', 'Country']]
print (df)
   Rank  Country
0     1        4
1     2        5
2     3        6
```

---

```
df = a[['Rank', 'Country']]
print (df)
   Rank  Country
0     1        4
1     2        5
2     3        6
```

You can also check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics):

> You can pass a list of columns to `[]` to select columns in that order.

Also for select column to one column `DataFrame` use `[]` too:

```
df = a[['Rank']]
print (df)
   Rank
0     1
1     2
2     3
```

but for `Series`:

```
s = a['Rank']
print (s)
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: Rank, dtype: int64
```